# Как открыть Excel и получить адрес выбраной ячейки?

Tags: c#, excel

Есть Excel файл. Нужно открыть его в Excel и определить куда нажал пользователь (какую ячейку выбрал). Есть идеи?

Comment: Вроде, при переоткрытии Excel средствами Office он автоматически выбирает последнюю активную страницу и ячейку.

Comment: *Пользователь выбрал ячейку*... Когда? После открытия или нужно определить последнюю выбранную перед закрытием? А если файл не сохранялся? /// *Нужно открыть... и определить...* - если при открытии, то пользователь еще не успел ничего нажать )

Comment: Ну я уже уговорил заказчика, на то, что сам отрисую таблицу в DataGrid. 
Но все же интересно, можно ли было это сделать средствами excel. 
Я довольно прямо написал:
Алгоритм должен быть такой:
1. Открываем excel(программно).
2. Дожидаемся пока пользователь тыкнет какую-нибудь ячейку. 
3. Закрываем excel и отдаем результат - адрес ячейки.